# Error MultiValueDictKeyError en request.get en django

Tags: python, django

Eso pues, tengo el siguiente código en `datastore.py`:

```
class DatastoreAPI(View):
    def get(self, request):
        type = request.GET['type'] if 'type' in request.GET else None
        stationId = request.GET['stationid'] if 'stationid' in request.GET else None
        sensorId = request.GET['sensorid'] if 'sensorid' in request.GET else None
        objectId = request.GET['objectid']
        print(objectId)
        ...
```

Puse los `...` acá porque el código es más largo y lo importante está en estas líneas

Y este es parte de `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('web/tracking/reportes', tracking_views.DatastoreAPI.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

Bueno pues, cuando voy a la URL, me sale este error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /web/tracking/reportes
'objectid'
```

Y en la consola no imprime el `objectid`, sino me sale el error.

¿Saben cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: en primer lugar no uses palabras reservadas para los nombres de variables, y verifica lo que trae la petición haciendo un `print(request.GET)` y tambien puedes ahorrarte el operador ternario si usas el método `get` de los diccionarios

Comment: ese type ya estaba, solo que le añadi otras variables

Comment: y con respecto al ````print(request.GET)```` me sale esto: ````<QueryDict: {}>````, lo cual creo que es raro porque en el resto no sale el error

Answer (score 0):

Si vas a intentar obtener valores de esta manera: request.GET['objectid'] primero necesitas verificar que exista el key antes de intentar obtener el valor. Puedes hacerlo de estas maneras que te presento:

```
class DatastoreAPI(View):
    def get(self, request):
        type = request.GET['type'] if 'type' in request.GET else None
        stationId = request.GET['stationid'] if 'stationid' in request.GET else None
        sensorId = request.GET['sensorid'] if 'sensorid' in request.GET else None

        # Manera larga
        if objectid in request.GET:
          objectId = request.GET['objectid']
        else:
          objectId = None

        # Manera simplificada
        objectId = request.GET.get('objectid', None)

        print(objectId)
        ...
```

De la primer forma primero revisas que tengas el key dentro de tu request.GET entonces así ya puedes obtener su valor y en caso de que no este el key presente entonces le asignas None a tu variable.

De la segunda manera es la versión simplificada de la primera, se usa la función get() y va así:

```
variable = mi_diccionario.get(<key>, <default>)
```

Intentas obtener el 'key' de mi_diccionario, en caso de no existir le asigna por defecto el valor .

De esta manera tu print te mostrara el valor si esta presente en request.GET y de caso contrario te imprimirá un None